# CXX1405 Error When Building HelloJNI Sample Project on Windows 10

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I have a C++ Build error when Building the HelloJNI Sample project downloaded from Android Studio.

Windows 10
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.0.0 Patch 2.

```
[CXX1405] error when building with cmake using


C:\Users\az01799\AndroidStudioProjects\HelloJNI\app\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt: 
        C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
        @echo off
        "C:\\Users\\az01799\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.18.1\\bin\\cmake.exe" ^
          "-HC:\\Users\\az01799\\AndroidStudioProjects\\HelloJNI\\app\\src\\main\\cpp" ^
          "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android" ^
          "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON" ^
          "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=23" ^
          "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23" ^
          "-DANDROID_ABI=x86" ^
          "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=x86" ^
          "-DANDROID_NDK=C:\\Users\\az01799\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\25.1.8937393" ^
          "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=C:\\Users\\az01799\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\25.1.8937393" ^
          "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=
    C:\\Users\\az01799\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\25.1.8937393\\build\\cmake\\android.toolchain.cmake" ^
          "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=
    C:\\Users\\az01799\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.18.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
          "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=
    C:\\Users\\az01799\\AndroidStudioProjects\\HelloJNI\\app\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\50l44586\\obj\\x86" ^
          "-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=
    C:\\Users\\az01799\\AndroidStudioProjects\\HelloJNI\\app\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\50l44586\\obj\\x86" ^
          "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ^
          "-BC:\\Users\\az01799\\AndroidStudioProjects\\HelloJNI\\app\\.cxx\\Debug\\50l44586\\x86" ^
          -GNinja
      from C:\Users\az01799\An

droidStudioProjects\HelloJNI\app
Affected Modules: app
```

I am stuck on this issue since I started working on a new Windows 10 PC.

Has anybody got the same issue building the HelloJNI sample? It seems to be related to C++ compilation, but the error message is not really pointing to what is causing the error.

Still same Errors when:

- I restart with Invalidate caches
- I do Build >> Refresh Linked C++ projects
- Sync with Gradle
- It seems related to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34871)

But I have not found the solution for this problem.

I don't have any other CMake installation other than the one installed by Android Studio in:

```
C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake
```

Comment: try running the same command manually from the same cwd and [edit] to show what you see.

Comment: Thanks for your reply : I tried to manually  execute the command from the same directory 
  C:\Users\az01799\AndroidStudioProjects\HelloJNI\app
First it does not accept  '^'  as a line break, so I used '|' instead.

Error message says "-HC" is not recognized as an applet, function, script file or executable program

Comment: If I copy paste the command as is without any Line separator, prompt just returns with no message

Comment: What if you run it with [`--verbose`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-v)?

Comment: I don't know if that is the issue but when I run cmake command alone (or cmake -help).
Prompt does not return anything, cmake is ignored :

I have another WIn10 PC where it works fine :
 C:\Users\az01799\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\\cmake\3.18.1\bin\cmake.exe --help
>>
Usage
  cmake [options] <path-to-source>
  cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>
etc...
>>>

Comment: Only difference I can see between the 2 versions of WIndows is the language.
In Win 10  / French, Powershell console language is in french and cmake command is ignored by Powershell.
On WIn10 / english , cmake command works fine in the Power shell

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem, it is not related to language in WIndows, When I run cmake from a Power SHell (PS) , I get no error message :

PS: C:\Users\az01799\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\cmake.exe --help

But when I run the same command from a cmd console, I get an pop-up explicit error message saying "MSVCP140.dll can not be found" and asking to install it.

This .dll is a part of a 2015 Microsoft Visual Studio redistributable, I could install it from https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Now HelloJNI sample is building OK, I have been stuck for weeks because of this issue, nothing was telling me that this .dll is missing, there should be a more explicit message from Power SHell, PS seems to filter/ignore errors